# Updating data in two table. one which contain multiple data in one column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to update my data inside two tables at once (maklumatakaun , detailakaun) in detailakaun there are  column 'KodLokasi' 'KodJenisAkaun' and 'NoTelefon' that could have more than one data entry under one id. Here's what i got so far

```
extract ($_POST);

if ($_POST) {

    $NoAkaun            = isset($_POST['NoAkaun'])          ? $_POST['NoAkaun'] : '';
    $KodBahagian        = isset($_POST['KodBahagian'])      ? $_POST['KodBahagian'] : '';
    $Tarif              = isset($_POST['Tarif'])            ? $_POST['Tarif'] : '';
    $KodDaerah          = isset($_POST['KodDaerah'])        ? $_POST['KodDaerah'] : '';
    $KodKategori        = isset($_POST['KodKategori'])      ? $_POST['KodKategori'] : '';
    $NoTelefon          = isset($_POST['NoTelefon'])        ? $_POST['NoTelefon'] : '';
    $KodLokasi          = isset($_POST['KodLokasi'])        ? $_POST['KodLokasi'] : '';
    $KodJenisAkaun      = isset($_POST['KodJenisAkaun'])    ? $_POST['KodJenisAkaun'] : '';
    $akaun_id           = isset($_POST['akaun_id'])         ? $_POST['akaun_id'] : '';






    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE maklumatakaun
                        SET NoAkaun = '$NoAkaun' , 
                        KodBahagian = '$KodBahagian' , 
                        KodDaerah = '$KodDaerah' , 
                        KodKategori = '$KodKategori' , 
                        Tarif = '$Tarif' , 
                        WHERE id = '$id'");
    $akaun_id = mysql_insert_id();
    foreach ($NoTelefon AS $i => $telefon){
    $sql= mysql_query ("UPDATE detailakaun
                        SET KodJenisAkaun = '$KodJenisAkaun[$i]' ,  
                        KodLokasi = '$KodLokasi[$i]' , 
                        NoTelefon = '$telefon'
                        ");
```

This code would update all the columns inside the two table but lets say one account have was registered with 3 'KodLokasi' , 'KodJenisAkaun', and 'NoTelefon' then when updated with only one of the 3 columns it will repeat itself to 3. How can i update this properly?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($NoTelefon AS $i => $telefon){
$sql= mysql_query ("UPDATE detailakaun
                    SET KodJenisAkaun = '$KodJenisAkaun[$i]' ,  
                    KodLokasi = '$KodLokasi[$i]' , 
                    NoTelefon = '$telefon'
                    ");
```

$NoTelefon have 3 data and using foreach forces to loop over 3 times

Just use 1 query with 3 data

```
$sql= mysql_query ("UPDATE detailakaun
                    SET KodJenisAkaun = '$KodJenisAkaun[1]' ,  
                    KodLokasi = '$KodLokasi[1]' , 
                    NoTelefon = '$NoTelefon[1]'
                    ");
```

Hope This Gives An Idea To Format Query First Then Execute

Comment: so you suggesting to enter the number in first place? I don't get it to be honest sir

Comment: Depends on $NoTelefon. What you see when you just execute print_r($NoTelefon); ?